# How to autocomplete a block signature in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When I'm writing a function that takes a block, I see the signature highlighted, but hitting tab will not autocomplete the signature. I am forced to type out the entire signature. The below example is not that hard to type, but I often run into cases where the signature is quite long and my short-term memory is not good enough to type the whole thing. The dilemma is that once I start typing, the signature disappears, offering no help in completing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to press <kbd>enter</kbd> after highlighting it.

It works, and it even open the brackets for you.

Comment: Yep, that's what I do.

Comment: @Rich Thanks, I hesitated to change for "the block even opens your arms for you" :)

Comment: Hahaha, I originally meant the "I used to work" to "it works", but this one is even better :)